# Deploying a Data-Tier Project on SQL Azure - Pre and Post Deployment use the master DB

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-sql-database, data-tier-applications

I'm using a Data Tier DB project to deploy on Azure, everything goes fine, the DB and the schema are well created except that during the pre and post deployment it always tries to use the master DB instead of the one I specified under "Deploy - Data Tier Application Instance Name" in the properties. I tried to use a USE MyDB statement but it is not supported.

Of course I would like the pre and post deployment scripts to be executed on the current DB I'm creating. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Best regards.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one struggling with this. Did you ever find a way around this?

Comment: I have the same problem. I hope someone has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not possible to use the PostDeployment script functionality with SQL Azure.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/windowsazuredata/thread/07f36eb1-5ae7-4c5c-aa1d-ecab903cc6a7